# Django - Filter by multiple values (Logical AND) on ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build job-candidate match system.

I want to filter Candidates by Critical Skills needed for the Job.
Every candidate has multiple skills.
Every Job has multiple 'required' JobSkill which is a model that also contains importance of the skill.

I want to filter my candidates and to get only candidates how have **all** the critical skills required for a job.
A critical skill is defined as a JobSkill with importance = 3.

For a given job 'job_1' I want to get the relevant candidates as follows:

```
critical_skills = job_1.required_skills.filter(importance=3)
relevant_candidates = Candidate.objects.filter('candidate how has all the critical_skills)
```

models.py:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)

class JobSkill(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Importance(models.IntegerChoices):
        HIGH = 3
        MEDIUM = 2
        LOW = 1

    importance = models.IntegerField(choices=Importance.choices)


class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    required_skills = models.ManyToManyField(JobSkill, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  


class Candidate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True)
```

I would appreciate any help with this!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply chain the filters as per [Spanning multi-valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships), when spanning multi-valued relationships in a filter we restrict the related model with each filter. So you can do as follows:

```
relevant_candidates = Candidate.objects.all()

for job_skill in critical_skills:
    relevant_candidates = relevant_candidates.filter(skills__id=job_skill.skill_id)
```

> **Note**: As the amount of critical skills would increase this would make more and more joins causing the query to grow more complicated
> and the results would be quite slow.

> **Note**: Instead of having a `ManyToManyField` with the table `JobSkill` which only has a  foreign key to `Skill` and a field
> `importance` you should simply have a `ManyToManyField` with `Skill`
> and have a custom through model that would have a foreign key to both
> `Job` and `Skill` and the field `importance`. See [Extra fields on
> many-to-many
> relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)